# pd.Grouper with datetime key in conjunction with another grouping key seemingly creates the wrong number of groups

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

Using pd.Grouper with a datetime key in conjunction with another key creates a set of groups, but this does not seem to encompass all of the groups that need to be created, in my opinion.

```
>>> test = pd.DataFrame({"id":["a","b"]*3, "b":pd.date_range("2000-01-01","2000-01-03", freq="9H")})
>>> test
    id  b
0   a   2000-01-01 00:00:00
1   b   2000-01-01 09:00:00
2   a   2000-01-01 18:00:00
3   b   2000-01-02 03:00:00
4   a   2000-01-02 12:00:00
5   b   2000-01-02 21:00:00
```

When I tried to create groups based on the date and `id` values:

```
>>> g = test.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='b', freq="D"), 'id'])
>>> g.groups
{(2000-01-01 00:00:00, 'a'): [0], (2000-01-02 00:00:00, 'b'): [1]}
```

`g.groups` shows only 2 groups when I expected 4 groups: both "a" and "b" for each day.

However, when I created another column based off of "b":

```
>>> test['date'] = test.b.dt.date
>>> g = test.groupby(['date', 'id'])
>>> g.groups
{(2000-01-01, 'a'): [0, 2], (2000-01-01, 'b'): [1], (2000-01-02, 'a'): [4], (2000-01-02, 'b'): [3, 5]}
```

The outcome was exactly what I expected.

I don't know how to make sense of these different outcomes. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have 4 groups with the `Grouper`, the output of `g.groups` is misleading (maybe worth reporting as a bug?):

```
g = test.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='b', freq="D"), 'id'])

g.ngroups
# 4

g.size()
# b           id
# 2000-01-01  a     2
#             b     1
# 2000-01-02  a     1
#             b     2
# dtype: int64
```

Comment: This does seem buggy to me.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I can see that it indeed created 4 groups. Could you give me an explanation about why `[pd.Grouper(key='b', freq='D'), 'id']` only gives 2 group keys?

Comment: @VJ.BG I don't see any good reason. As said in my answer you probably should [report it as a bug](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/contributing.html#bug-reports-and-enhancement-requests).

Comment: @VJ.BG Great catch.... submit a bug report.  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues

Comment: You can provide the link to the bug report for reference in your question if/when you do report it.

Comment: Done! https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/51158 Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because of the difference between 'pd.Grouper' and the 'dt.date' method in pandas. 'pd.Grouper' groups by a range of values (e.g., daily, hourly, etc.) while 'dt.date' returns just the date part of a datetime object, effectively creating a categorical variable.

When you use 'pd.Grouper' with a frequency of "D", it will group by full days, so each day is represented by only one group. But in your case, each id has multiple records for a given day. So, 'pd.Grouper' is not able to capture all of the groups that you expect.

On the other hand, when you use the 'dt.date' method to extract the date part of the datetime, it creates a categorical variable that represents each date independently.

so when you group by this new date column along with the id column, each group will correspond to a unique combination of date and id, giving you the expected outcome.

In summary, pd.Grouper is useful when you want to group by a range of values (e.g., daily, hourly), while using a separate column for the exact values (e.g., a column for dates only) is useful when you want to group by specific values.

Comment: Nope, textbook answer

Comment: OK, my bad then, but still incorrect IMO (see my answer that shows the 4 groups)

Comment: oh, the 'g.groups' shows two groups, but the 'g.ngroups' shows 4 groups and 'g.size()' show the count of elements in the groups. correctly. Definitely a bug. Thanks @mozway. Guess i have to go get an updated textbook then.